# How to achieve this menu drop animation?

Tags: android, animation, menu, material-design, transition

Well I tried to make menu animation like the below one:
[image]

From this [site](https://dribbble.com/shots/1830536-Menu-drop-animation)

But so far I have failed. I tried using ObjectAnimator, TranstionSet and other but unable to get the same effect. What I got is this..[see below pic]

[image]

**My images bouncing on its own place**. Please do understand that my objective is to get the same transition/animation effect for these images. I tried searching on web but in vain, saw lots of code about animations with no explanation. It will be grateful if anyone can provide code or guide me to achieve this animation. I am really confused with transition and animation library of android. Any help will be appreciated. Note: reverse effect[exit] in the above pic also

My current code for reference (I did tried other ways[failed] also.)
layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cal_menu"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF9900"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_paste"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_paste"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_paste"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_paste"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_paste"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img6"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_paste"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
  private void initializeDummyFields(View view){
    cal_menu = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.cal_menu);
    img1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img1);
    img2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img2);
    img3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img3);
    img4 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img4);
    img5 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img5);
    img6 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img6);
}

private void dummyAnimation(){
    cal_menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 1);
    animation.setDuration(300);
    cal_menu.setAnimation(animation);
    animation.start();

    Animation animation6 =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    animation6.setDuration(1000);
    animation6.setStartOffset(300);
    animation6.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    img6.setAnimation(animation6);
    animation6.start();

    Animation animation5 =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    animation5.setDuration(1000);
    animation5.setStartOffset(400); //setting different startOffset so they start at different time
    animation5.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    img5.setAnimation(animation5);
    animation5.start();

    Animation animation4 =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    animation4.setDuration(1000);
    animation4.setStartOffset(500);
    animation4.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    img4.setAnimation(animation4);
    animation4.start();

    Animation animation3 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    animation3.setDuration(1000);
    animation3.setStartOffset(600);
    animation3.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    img3.setAnimation(animation3);
    animation3.start();

    Animation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    animation2.setDuration(1000);
    animation2.setStartOffset(700);
    animation2.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    img2.setAnimation(animation2);
    animation2.start();

    Animation animation1 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    animation1.setDuration(1000);
    animation1.setStartOffset(800);
    animation1.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    img1.setAnimation(animation1);
    animation1.start();
}
```

Comment: Try this one, remove 0 dp width from one image and check the result.

Comment: @Arjun why do you think that will even work ? I think that is not the problem. The problem is properly writing the animation/transition code. Still I wanted to leave no chance and tried what you said, and quite obvious it didn't work. Thanks anyway.